# Using SSL without a certificate

Tags: security, ssl, https, embedded, certificate

Embedded devices often need security for transmitted data. Think of your wifi router. You would like to have SSL to protect your password when you connect to the router manage it. But device manufacturers cannot expect users to install certificates (too much hassle).

So we have a problem, how to use SSL with embedded devices, but without the hassle of installing a unique cert in each device. Self-signed certs can work, but the browser warnings scare the common user.

SSL provides 2 things:
1. Verify the identity of the server
2. Encrypt communications

For embedded devices, we can do without the first, but we often really want the second. So what we want is to either use SSL without a cert, or to be able to use a self-signed cert without the warnings. The self-signed cert warnings in browsers scare the common user. So what to do?

It seems there is no good solution for embedded devices to use SSL?

Ideas?

Answer (score 3):

> SSL provides 2 things: 1. Verify the identity of the server 2. Encrypt communications
>
> For embedded devices, we can do without the first, but we often really want the second. So what we want is to either use SSL without a cert, or to be able to use a self-signed cert without the warnings. The self-signed cert warnings in browsers scare the common user.

Your question suggests that you don't really understand the role of identification in SSL.

Encryption without identification of the peer allows an attacker to mount a man-in-the-middle attack. In this attack the client will have an encrypted connection to the attacker and the attacker has another encrypted connection to the server. The attacker will get the encrypted data from the client, decrypt it and forward it encrypted again to the server. The same is done for data from the server to the client. This way the attacker can listen and even modify the data. Neither server nor client can detect the attack because of missing identification of the peer.

If the client wants to have a trusted connection to the device it needs to establish trust first. With self-signed certificate this will be done by accepting the certificate once within the browser (but only if there is definitely no man-in-the-middle). From then on any man-in-the-middle attacks will be detected because the certificate has changed.

Comment: Without SSL, there is not identification. With a self-signed cert, there is no "real" identification. So we then lose all encryption because we don't have identification. But if it is a WIFI gateway that is 100% generic, does anyone have any scalable, manufacturable idea for how to get good, secure password encryption?  If you can't use SSL because of no cert, then login passwords are in the clear. Digest Auth with MD5 is insufficient.

Comment: With self-signed there is no real identification on the first connection, unless you explicitly check the fingerprints. Thus this connection must be done through channel which is known to be secure. But, for all future connections it will be checked if the received certificate matches the already known certificate, so a real identification is done. "... Digest Auth with MD5 is insufficient." - I think what you are missing is a clearly defined scenario against what kind of attacks your solution should protect.

Comment: There are many scenarios, but take a user connecting to a WIFI router using WIFI to manage it. Something many users do. The password will be sent in the clear unless SSL is used, but the burden of certificates makes this effectively impossible for manufacturers to provision. Someone sniffing WIFI packets (easy to do) can then capture the password with ease. There are many other scenarios like this for embedded devices.

Comment: These are not clearly defined scenarios. Such scenarios would contain among others assumptions about the expected capabilities of the attackers and the user and what security trade-offs you are willing to take. As an example: a WLAN access point for some branch office of the NSA is probably a different scenario then a public access point which is again different from a access point for a family only. You always need to take a balance between security, necessary education and ease of use and you need to know what risk is acceptable.

Comment: I understand this, but you've not yet suggested what a device manufacturer can do. What are the workable options for improved password security. I see none?

Comment: If I have a look at Fritz!Box (the most uses DSL router in Germany): they have a self-signed certificate but offer to upload your own certificate. And they educate users what this means.